# Can't make selectors work on an html table

Tags: html, css

Wondering why selectors are not working in an html table from the css.

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black
}

tr.1 {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="1"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

all in all i'm trying to make a tic tac toe board by showing certain borders on the 9 table spots. Can't figure out how to select just one "td" at a time to turn the borders on that I need.

Comment: Your rule is the selector `tr.1` but it's the cell that has the class. E.g. `td.1`. You should also avoid numeric CSS classes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but class names cannot start with a digit.

Via  [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters)

Comment: That, in addition to what @j08691 mentioned.